# Hide Gridview FooterRow on print

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I've setup a print.css to hide elements of my web form to make a "printer friendly" version of the page, but I'm running into a stumbling block trying to hide the footer row.

Print.css

```
body {
}
@media print {
    .NoPrint {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

I can set the following on the "Command" column and the link buttons are hidden on Print Preview, but the link button in the FooterRow is still there.

```
<asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False" HeaderStyle-BackColor="Silver" ControlStyle-CssClass="NoPrint">
```

I can add `CssClass="NoPrint"` to the LinkButton in the command column and it disappears fine. However, on print, I'd just rather have the footer row itself be hidden on the print/print preview. I could tag `CssClass="NoPrint"` to each element in the footer row, but there are text boxes that already have a CssClass defined for them.

Is there another way I can hide the footer row on my gridviews to make this more printer friendly?

Comment: An element can have more than one class: `CssClass="myClass NoPrint"`

Comment: Don't know why I never considered trying multiple classes.... Sometimes you don't see the forest through the trees. Still, a bit of a pain that I have to class each control in the footer row as opposed to being able to class the whole row. Oh well, this gets me what I need.

Comment: You could do that also: `<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" FooterStyle-CssClass="myClass NoPrint"`

Comment: That, sir, is a thing of beauty. I figured there had to be a simpler way.